# Do we have a configuration setting to provide custom class for Read Fields in JasperSoft Studio 6 onwards

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

In old iReports Designer, we have query dialog where we can run sql queries and procs to fetch data. There was a "Read Fields" button used to fetch all the fields returned from the proc's cursor and display it into the fields list. iReport Designer use to provide a way to configure how read fields work by providing custom class.

Now after upgrading to JasperStudio 6.0.x, it looks like the setting where we can provide the custom SQLFieldsProvider that can run and fetch fields from the proc is not there anymore...

Is there any other property or setting which is supposed to be used so as to provide custom class value to SQLFieldsProvider or is it even possible to do that anymore in Studio?

[image: OLD iReportDesigner setting screen where we specify query executor and fields provider]